# DoNotTrack field update for new contacts in All Subscribers List

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, gdpr, email-tracking

I have a following issue:

I have Marketing Cloud account with several Business Units.

In some Business Units I should disable tracking of customers behaviour (due to GDPR restrictions), in other Business Units the tracking should remain enabled.

I created DoNotTrack field in the Preference Management. However, I cannot set the default value of this field, cause for different Business Units the default value should be different. That's why for Business Units that need to disable the tracking I created an automation which uses AMPscript and API to update existing contacts (this automation updates DoNotTrack field value to 'True').

The problem is with contacts who are being added to All Subscribers List in the moment of sending the first message. The default value is not set, so the DoNotTrack field value remains empty and the behaviour is tracked. I tried to implement a script in the email, but since this script uses 'CreateObject' command, it is not allowed.

Do you have any suggestions what I should do?

Comment: We need to know the process how you get new subscribers. This process matters the most because you would like to change it that the value will be set while creating the new subscriber. Atleast that is the most convinient one. Otherwise you would have to create automations / scripts with schedules or special triggers

Comment: I would recommend adding a field to the Sendable DE called DoNotTrack and populate it with the default value. this will then set the profile attribute at send time when adding the subscriber to 'All Subs'

Comment: @EazyE, are you sure this approach works? Haven't tried but it almost sounds too easy for marketing cloud ;)

Comment: @StephandePaly if I remember correctly when i tested it a few mths ago, this is how it worked. I know the DE approach is the most straight forward especially when dealing with multiple BU and having different donottrack use cases

Comment: @EazyE interesting! I will certainly test this. Especially if this also works for data extension based journey builder sends. Unfortunately it's very unlikely to work for salesforce based entry events as the field name pattern is broken by default. I will report on the results

Comment: Testresult: Auto-update based on data extension fields works for manual and user initiated sends. It DOES NOT WORK for Journey Builder sends (All Subscribers set as publication list). Triggered sends seem to work differently here.

Comment: Correct it does not work for salesforce based sends since the naming pattern is not correct. JB does not update any profile attribute so I can see this not working either. But other TS do